# Simple poisson regression for a death rate

Tags: regression, econometrics, poisson-regression, intuition, offset

I am trying to regress the death rate for a particular cause of death for 25-30 year olds. My dependent variable of interest is the crude rate, i.e., y = number of deaths of 25-30 year olds/number of people 25-30 year old in a county.

If I were to run this as a Poisson regression, would I run this on the count of deaths of 25-30 year olds (the numerator) on my regressors, and include the log of the denominator (number of people 25-30) as a regressor as an offset?

Is the idea thinking of the link function, let deaths = number of  25-30 year olds dying from the cause, and n = the number of 25-30 year olds

\begin{align}  \newcommand{\deaths}{{\rm deaths}}
\frac{\deaths}{n} &= e^{x'\beta}  \\[5pt]
\deaths   &= ne^{x'\beta}  \\[5pt]
\deaths   &= e^{x'\beta + \ln(n)}
\end{align}

and this last equation is Poisson link function?

Comment: I can't quite parse a couple of your sentences.  I'm not sure if you're asking if you should use ln(n) as a regressor or an offset.  I'm also not sure if you're asking if the derivation is right or what, exactly. Either way, I think you'll find the info you need in the linked thread.